# error with transferring files from android to laptop

Tags: kali-linux, android, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer files from the main storage of my android phone to my kali laptop via usb cable. Every time I try it gives me a error saying:

```
Error getting file: -6 Not Supported.
```

I also tried installing gmtp, but it gives me a error saying:

```
Error getting file from mtp device.
```

I also dont have internet access on this machine.

Comment: What commands are you using to try to access your files? Is your phone in debug\developer mode?

Comment: Yes my phone is in debug mode. And I am just dragging the file over to my home folder.

Comment: Is this from a SD card or main storage? I'm not an Android person, but I want to try and make it easier for someone who is to help.

Comment: It's from the main storage.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer specifically, but the easiest way to do this is not to use a USB cable but an app like airdroid. It's available as a free version. Since I discovered this app, I no longer worry about USB debugging mode; developer options and finding my USB phone cable.

Comment: Although this application sounds great , for the time being I do not have internet access to download it.

Comment: Hm OK, you didn't mention that rather important fact in your original question. I'd ensure you have mtp-tools installed, it may be called something else in your distro. Do you? 
Additionally some file managers (like the one I use) allow one to transfer to another device on a lan via ssh. Maybe try that if all else fails?

Did you do a Google search on your error? Quite a few hits: Might wanna check them out too: https://goo.gl/xi5BOH